# openvpn isn't listening at any port

Tags: networking, server, openvpn

I've installed openvpn on my Ubuntu 18.04lts but I just can't get it to listen to any ports!

I have no idea why..
my server.conf isn't so big;

```
    hellfire:~]cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf

    local 192.168.0.11
port 1194
    proto udp
    dev tun
    ca /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
    cert /etc/openvpn/server/dummy-server.crt
    key /etc/openvpn/server/dummy-server.key
    dh /etc/openvpn/server/dh.pem
    server 10.77.0.0 255.255.255.0
    #push "redirect-gateway def1"
    
    #push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.88.88"
    duplicate-cn
    cipher AES-256-CBC
    tls-version-min 1.2
    cipher AES-256-CBC
    auth SHA512
    auth-nocache
    keepalive 20 60
    persist-key
    persist-tun
    compress lz4
    daemon
    user nobody
    group nogroup
    log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
    verb 3
```

and when I check if openvpn is listening, I get the answer:

```
hellfire:~]sudo netstat -uap|grep openvpn
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:openvpn         0.0.0.0:*                           816/openvpn
```

and now, 2 days later, and I'm still stuck..

openvpn are running, and I'm not seeing anything wrong, except it's deaf...

Comment: is this a VPS?  Is this a system running at your home?  How're you trying to connect to it?  From behind a router?  From outside your network?  From the local network?  All this is information we're going to need to debug anything.

Comment: It's an running virtual box Ubuntu 18, and I've been trying to connect to it from my router. vps? no idea..  shouldn't the port appear when I'm checking for what ports  that are listening. if I run: sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN , then openvpn isn't even listed

Comment: How is it configured on the network side of things for the VM?  If it's in VirtualBox, it isn't going to be listening directly on the computer's interface in a default setup, you'd have to set up port forwarding from the host computer to make it work.  You won't be able to get your router to connect directly to the VM in the default setup (which uses NAT on the VBox side)

Comment: port forward is fixed, the virtual box network is set to bridged, so 192.168.0.11 is the Ubuntus own ip..

Comment: sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN isn't even listing openvpn in the list..

Comment: Try using `ss -tulp | grep -i openvpn` and see if you have anything that has 'LISTEN' (I don't trust lsof or netstat anymore).   If you didn't configure OPenVPN to autostart in 'server' mode then it won't be listening (check `/var/log/syslog` and `journalctl -u openvpn.service` for error messages if it *is* configured with the service enabled).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125012/discussion-between-adam-larsson-and-thomas-ward).

Comment: Ubuntu 18?  No such system, is this is a Ubuntu Core 18 system? and not a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system?   Please be precise & accurate with details.